# How to get all Video ads which are associated with campaigns which have started this year

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I'm not sure what to put in the `withCondition` to get all such videoAds.

```
var videoAds = AdsApp
                .videoAds()
                .withCondition('????')                    
                .get();

while (videoAds.hasNext()) {
    var videoAd = videoAds.next();
    data.push([
        videoAd.getVideoCampaign().getId(),
        videoAd.getVideoCampaign().getName(),
        videoAd.getVideoAdGroup().getId(),
        videoAd.getVideoAdGroup().getName(),
        videoAd.getId(),
        videoAd.getName(),
    ]);
}
```